# Is it possible to hold a active incoming call in android

Tags: android, android-intent

Thanks in advance ., i need a small help from you all . please guide me.

I want to hold a incoming call in in my application . please tell is it possible or not if its not possible then why ??

Because i need explain to my client why we cant achieve that functionality.

thanks once again.

Comment: Can any one plese help me.. tell me is call hoild is possible or not .. please its very urgent for me.

Comment: No one know how to do that then how some people has implimentd this in there applications..

Comment: I have the same issue now. U got any sollutions for this issue or not if yes then pls update the solutions.